# Is sudo required for installing VMware Tools?

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, sudo, vmware-tools

I'm trying to install VMware Tools in Ubuntu 16.04. Should I do this by using `sudo`? Why?

Comment: Did you try to run the installation without `sudo`? What happened? Maybe the error message is a good start for an answer to your question.

Comment: Can anybody tell why this question is not marked as duplicate as the OP wants to know why to use `sudo` and there are already lot of answers explain the same ?

Comment: I didn't mark it as a duplicate, because the OP didn't ask *why* use sudo, vico asked *if* sudo is required and it will come up again and again until someone finally answers yes sudo is required or no sudo is not required and then the next time someone asks if sudo is required that question can be marked as a duplicate of this one. Maybe an unfocused duplicate question would be better in some cases, but that was my reasoning for not voting to close this question.

Comment: @karel Thanks for explaining. Got it now. I have marked your answer as useful as it explains the the commands and why we need to use those commands and other useful informations. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On 14.04 and later open-vm-tools from the default Ubuntu repositories is the recommended method of installing VMware Tools on Ubuntu. The Open Virtual Machine Tools (*open-vm-tools*) project is an open source implementation of VMware Tools. It is a suite of virtualization utilities and drivers to improve the functionality, user experience and administration of VMware virtual machines. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install open-vm-tools open-vm-tools-desktop open-vm-tools-dkms
```

This command will return an error message if you run it without `sudo` unless you run it as a root user, the same as for installing .deb packages from the default Ubuntu repositories with `apt` in general.

For descriptions of what these three packages do, run the following command which doesn't require `sudo` because it doesn't install anything:

```
apt show open-vm-tools open-vm-tools-desktop open-vm-tools-dkms
```

Answer (score 1):

You typically install software using `sudo` in order to elevate your privileges, because without root privileges you cannot write to files in locations where the guest addition tools should reside on the disk.  Note, that in Linux world it is an established practice not to use the root (administrator) account for day-to-day tasks, but rather use the `sudo` command to elevate your privileges to run a single command.

In order to install any software system-wide (e.g. with access to devices), you will have to write in locations like `/usr/lib` where you have no write permission when on a day-to-day user account.  You could theoretically install a program in your home directory using your limited permissions, but problems with access to devices may arise with some applications.

However, in order to use `sudo`, you need to be a sudoer.  In other words, you need your account to have access specified in

```
/etc/sudoers
```

In Ubuntu, by default, the first user to be created during installation is a member of the `sudo` group, members of which can run all commands with `sudo` due to this line in the aforementioned file:

```
# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

The standard way to give a user `sudo` access in Ubuntu is to add them to the `sudo` group:

```
sudo adduser username sudo
```

In other distributions the group name may be difference, but you can find it when you view the sudo config file:

```
sudo cat /etc/sudoers
```

Note that you need root privilege just to read the sudoers file, so you need `sudo` for the `cat` command, unless you are using a root shell.